# Can you allow user to add another item without editing the administrator post?

Tags: nodes

I have a field which allows multiple inputs. What I want to achieve is to allow user to add another item only and not edit the content of the post of the admin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) for your node edit page and set '#disabled' => TRUE for your content field (assuming here as body field) by checking the current user role or something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I think you need to do right here is allow the user to edit nodes of that type, but then limit his ability to change any other field.

Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions and tell me if it suits your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried the field_permissions module. Even though you have restricted users on specific fields every time he/she edits the node the existing data still appears to be editable. I somehow wanted to disable editing existing content and just enable the Add another Item button.

Comment: You can make the existing data uneditable by changing it's access permissions via field_permissions. This means literally visiting each field to make them so, then you leave the field users should change data open for changes.